# Does SmtpClient support international email addresses (IDN/Intl email) in .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, idn

In .Net 4.5 SmtpClient have public property `DeliveryFormat` which accepts values of the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryFormat` type. So I can assign `DeliveryFormat` value `SmtpDeliveryFormat.International` and sends emails to the `дима@почта.рф` (cyrilic email address). But my current project supports only .Net 4.0 (customer restriction). In .Net 4.0 SmtpClient haven't both `SmtpClient.DeliveryFormat` property and `SmtpDeliveryFormat` type at all.

Now when using cyrilic emails I'm got an error: `The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: дима@почта.рф`.

I'm using SendGrid service for sending emails - it supports IDN addresses (http://sendgrid.com/docs/Marketing_Emails/recipients.html). Does this mean that I can't send emails to the IDN adresses using .Net 4.0?

Comment: I think you have the answer. No, it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah... It seems that I'm dreaming of a miracle

Comment: Yes, it's made according [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) and it allows only 7 bit US-ASCII characters. I never tried (and who knows how server will answer) but you may try to encode that characters as you may do for subject (according to RFC 2047).

Comment: Let me know if it works, I suppose, because it's not standard, it's not supported by servers.